# Laravel like query exact match

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm uploading a CSV file to my database and I want to automatically add a projecttype_id to a project, given this two project types:

1. Roads, new construction, widening
2. Roads, new construction

when I tried to upload "Roads, new construction" it always gives me the first id.

Tried removing % but still the same:

$projecttypeid = ProjectType::where('name', 'LIKE', "%{$projecttype}%")->first('id');

Comment: No need for `LIKE` if you want an exact match. `where('name', $projecttype)` should do it

Comment: Is the name exactly 'Roads, new construction, widening' or 'Roads, new construction'

Comment: thanks guys, for the first its Roads, new construction, widening (including RO-RO facilities) and some has single/double space like "RO - RO" or "RO  -RO"

Answer (score 2):

No need for LIKE if you want an exact match. where('name', $projecttype)